# Returning value from QObject's method that uses signals

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I can't figure out how to return value from function if it uses signals. Here's some code:

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.txt_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.btn_submit = QtWidgets.QPushButton('&Отправить')
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.txt_input)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btn_submit)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

class MyClass(QtCore.QObject):
    validated = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, window, *args, **kwargs)
        self.window = window
        self.arg = None

    def get_value(arg):
        self.arg = arg
        if arg == 0:
            self.window.btn_submit.connect(check_value)
            self.window.show()

    def check_value():
        self.window.hide()
        if window.txt_input.text == 'banana':
            self.validated.emit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = MyWindow()
    my_obj = MyClass(window)
    result = my_obj.get_value(0)
```

Of course, `get_value()` call will return None. I'd like to know how I can sync this code so in function `get_value()` I could wait for signal and then return something.

Comment: What are you showing is in a windows or should be embedded as a widget inside a parent window? Maybe you can show the window as a dialog.

Comment: application should be run just from console. And when I need input from user, then MyWindow should pop up.

Comment: Well, I think then that you should show your window as a dialog, when you do that the program flow stops until the window is closed and then you can collect the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `QDialog`, something like:

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.txt_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.btn_submit = QtWidgets.QPushButton('&Отправить')
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.txt_input)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btn_submit)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
```

And the call it as in:

```
def get_value(arg):
    self.arg = arg
    if arg == 0:
        self.window.btn_submit.connect(check_value)
        self.window.exec_()
```

After that collect the data you need.